# What is the pipeline a vkCmdPipelineBarrier applies to?

Tags: vulkan

vkCmdPipelineBarrier doesn't get any vkPipeline as parameter. So I am wondering  which pipeline a vkCmdPipelineBarrier applies to.

Is the one specified in a vkCmdBindPipeline command called earlier in the command buffer ? What if no pipeline was specified in the command buffer yet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't apply to any particular pipeline object; it applies to pipeline *stages* which execute action commands. Pipeline objects cause action commands (rendering, etc) to generate pipeline stage commands, but this is at best an indirect association.

Barriers are synchronization commands; as such, they have a source scope and a destination scope, between which the barrier apples. For `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`, the source scope is (usually) all commands given to the queue before the barrier call. These commands may be in the current command buffer or a previously submitted CB within the same `VkSubmitInfo` batch, or a submitted CB in a previous `vkQueueSubmit` call.

The destination scope is (usually) all commands given to the queue after the barrier call. Again, these may be commands in the same command buffer, in subsequently submitted CBs within the same batch, or in CBs submitted in subsequent calls to `vkQueueSubmit`.

For subpass self-dependency barriers, the source scope is all previously submitted commands within the current subpass (and therefore, by the transitive property, all commands on which the current subpass depends), and the destination scope is all subsequently submitted commands within the same subpass (and therefore, by the transitive property, all commands that have dependencies on the current subpass).

Comment: So a specific pipeline execution stage of all action commands in the second scope will be dependent of a specific pipeline stage of all commands in the first scope. The pipelines binded to these commands don't matter. That is what you meant by "indirect dependency" right ?

Comment: @alcoforado: I said "association", not dependency. Pipelines followed by action commands are what cause pipeline stages to be invoked. Barriers are dependencies between commands and pipeline stages. So they are associated with one another, but not in a "dependency" way.